# Error con schema, model y controller (mongoose)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy desarrollando una app con node.js, mongodb, mongoose y me surge un error cuando he añadido estos archivos.

Este es archivo "model.js":

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var RequestDiffSchema = new Schema({
  id: {
    type: Number,
    unique: true,
    required:true
  },
  solicitudId: { 
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  errors: { 
    type: String,
    required:true
  }
}, { collection: 'requestdiff' });

module.exports = mongoose.model('RequestDiff', RequestDiffSchema);
```

Y este el archivo "controller.js":

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    RequestDiff = mongoose.model('RequestDiff'),
    q = require('q'),
    Promise = q.Promise;


var RequestDiffController = {


  // Aquí van las funciones


};

module.exports = RequestDiffController;
```

**Me da error al levantar el server y no consigo solucionarlo, hice algo mal? algún error? o me falta algún paso?**

El error que me lanza por consola es:

```
Error initializing middleware
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "RequestDiff".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
    at Mongoose.model (/Documentos/api/backend.server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:349:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (Documentos/api/backend.server/api/controllers/requests-diff.js:7:28)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
```

Es porque no me coge bien el modelo?? Las rutas están correctas y no veo el fallo...

Comment: Qué hay en Documentos/api/backend.server/api/controllers/requests-diff.js:7:28 ?

Comment: Por otra parte, estás seguro que es correcto esta parte de model.js? **}, { collection: 'requestdiff' });**

Comment: requests-diff.js es lo que he llamado en el ejemplo "controller.js". Y la parte de , { collection: 'requestdiff' }); es la que apunta a la colleccion de mongodb, es esto correcto?? gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabo de solucionar el error. Al fin y al cabo era una tontería que me ha dado guerra, pero por si a alguien más le sucede...

El problema era que el atributo definido en el **Schema del model.js** como **"errors"** es una **palabra reservada de mongoose**. Lo he solucionado cambiando el nombre y ya funciona perfectamente!

Comment: me pasó hace tiempo lo mismo ;)

Comment: así pasa. Como sugerencia, me gusta visual studio code (aunque sea de Microsoft) porque me autocompleta código y me indica errores de sintaxis. Por ejemplo, si importo un objeto de mongoose en una variable x, y coloco un punto para acceder a una propiedad, me indica todas las opciones de ese objeto. Quizá al escribir palabras reservadas te des cuenta porque te aparezcan opciones de autocompletado

Comment: Lo que sí te ayuda a prevenir este tipo de errores e incluso bugs, es usar standard, un módulo de node basado en eslint. Este módulo te habría indicado el error más descriptivamente. Aquí lo puedes revisar: https://www.npmjs.com/package/standard